# Cron job not executing, no emails/logs

Tags: cron

My crontab looks like this while logged in as root:

`MAILTO=alex@xxxxxx.me
0 13 * * * cd /var/nodejs && sh restart.sh`

restart.sh

`#!/bin/sh
forever restartall`

Permissions

-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    29 Aug 26 19:50 restart.sh

However the forever processes never restart, if I run the cron command manually it works perfectly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have a directory '/var/nodejs'?

Comment: root@WL:/var/nodejs# yes :)